# Laravel getting ALL Users with Posts between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've got two tables related to each other:

```
Users:

id | name | email | phone

Posts:

id | user_id | body | start:date | end:date
```

They're related like: User can have many Posts:

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->with('comments');
}
```

and in Posts model:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

I need to get All Users with Posts where start between `[Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()]` and same condition for end column:

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q) use($currentMonth){
            return $q->whereBetween('start', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()])->orWhereBetween('end', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()]);
        })->get();
```

The main problem which I got is that I didn't get any User if condition is not OK. I need All Users, even if he doesn't have any posts, and the condition isn't valid, but the array of their Posts(or object array related) should be null.

So: I get all users with posts, if he/she matches the condition of date, get's only posts which match this, if he/she doesn't have posts or it didn't match condition in query his/her relation should be null or empty, but user should be added to collection.

Is it possible to achieve?

EDIT:

I got another problem. I've got form with the specific month page view(up to 12 future months). After selecting specific one I'm submitting form and passing it to Controller which look like that:

```
public function monthPage(Request $request)
    {
        $start = Carbon::parse($request['month'])->firstOfMonth();
        $end = Carbon::parse($request['month'])->lastOfMonth();

        $users = User::with(['posts' => function($q) use($start, $end){
            return $q->whereBetween('start', [$start->firstOfMonth(), $end->lastOfMonth()])
                ->orWhereBetween('end', [$start->firstOfMonth(), $end->lastOfMonth()]);
        }])->get();

        return view('posts.specific-month')
            ->with('users',$users);
    }
```

If Users has post with start on 20th of March and end on 20th May, the query isn't returning Posts for selection(in dropdown) of April.

I got for each month the page, so it works correct if I select March - it will display it until end of month and If I select May it will be displayed until 20th. If I select April, there's nothing to return, but this date is between 20th of March and 20th of May.

Comment: You are using whereHas it will limit your query. You should remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($q){
    return $q->whereBetween('start', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()])
        ->orWhereBetween('end', [Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth()]);
}])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I got problem, with getting data - if someone selects f.e. 20 of January as start and 20 March as end it isn't selected :/

Comment: what do you mean by that? What is not selected?

Comment: I mean, that I have month selection, to print specific month. So I pass via post the date of selected month and insert into your query as start and end. But f.e. if I someone goes with start of 20th March and end of 20th May, the April isn't selected when I try to print this.

Comment: So User declares starting date at 20th March and end date to 20th May. The query didn't return anything if I select date somwhere in April :/

Answer (score 1):

You should create a scope in the Post model:

```
public function applyDateRange(Carbon $start, Carbon $end)
{
   return $this->whereBetween('start', [$start, $end])
          ->orWhereBetween('end', [$start, $end]);
}
```

Then call the scope in the relation like this:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
   $q->applyDateRange(Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->lastOfMonth());
}])->get();
```

Comment: I got problem, with getting data - if someone selects f.e. 20 of January as start and 20 March as end it isn't selected :/

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Maybe post your new code and output.

Comment: I've added edit in my question